# Dangling modifiers

Tags: grammar, phrases

To succeed in any endeavor, commitment is necessary.

Anything wrong with this phrase? A dangling modifier?

Comment: There is a Wikipedia entry on *dangling modifiers* which should explain everything to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier

Comment: A dangling modifier is not wrong. It is merely dangling. That's why it's not called the wrong modifier.

Comment: 'Walking down the road, the garden gnomes looked very comical.' is more problematic than 'To succeed in any endeavor, commitment is necessary.' Deletions are common '_For a person_ to succeed in any endeavor, commitment is necessary.' and quite acceptable if they don't lead to absurdities or confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, "to succeed in any endeavor" does kind of dangle there, not saying what you want it to say, or not modifying what you want it to modify. Better would be:

> To succeed in any endeavor, *you* need to be committed to the endeavor.

Or,

> Commitment is essential to the success of any endeavor.

Or,

> Without commitment, you will not succeed in any endeavor.

Dangling modifiers can be quite humorous. For example,

> Walking into the intersection, the car almost knocked me down.

Who's doing the walking? The car? No, what you want to say is

> As I walked into the intersection, the car almost knocked me over.

In other words, *I* was doing the walking, not the car.